# How to attach an attribute to each element in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose we have an array with one attribute for each element:

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C [3] => D )
```

Is it possible to add the same uniform attribute to each of the elements, so that a new  two-dimensional array would be obtained? I.e. for attribute X:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => X)
        [1] => Array ( [0] => B [1] => X)
        [2] => Array ( [0] => C [1] => X) )
```

I know, I could do it using for each loop, but is there any more elegant solution (such as array_combine)?

(For assigning different values, please refer to: [Assigning a value to each array element PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906926/assigning-a-value-to-each-array-element-php))

Comment: Well, you could use `array_merge` by typecasting the current value to an array, merge it with an array with "X" allready in there for a single value. Use `array_walk` to apply this to all parts of the origional array. But I strongly doubt this is worth the effort. What's wrong with good old for loop? Would probably be clearer and cleaner then a very complicated, intelligent looking one-liner. In the end some code back there WILL loop over your initial array, so its not more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$array = array ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' );
$array = array_map(function($el) {
  return array($el, 'X');
}, $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_walk` could work as well.

```
$arr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
array_walk($arr, 'arrFunc');
function arrFunc(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = array($item, 'X'); 
}
```