# creating PHP arrays with two values

Tags: php

I want to be able to create an array like the below:

```
$array = array('one' => '1', 'two' => '2');
```

but by using code like this:

```
$array=array();
$array = 'one'

$array = 'two'
```

but how do i create the second part of each item in the array?

Comment: Try `$array['one'] = '1'` and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning a value to each array element PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906926/assigning-a-value-to-each-array-element-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php 
$array=array();
$array['one'] = 1;

$array['two'] = 2;
print_r($array);

?>
```

Comment: Exact copy from @suchit! Don't do that please

Comment: it was not copied, suchit's code contained some error which he has fixed in the edit

Comment: i am not sure weather it is copied... just see two answer within few seconds...BTW ... no problem..with this also

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php 
$array=array();
$array['one'] =1 ;

$array['two'] =2 ;
print_r($array);

?>
```

**NOTE:** if you want array with numeric key in your implementation you can do this:

```
<?php 
    $array=array();
    $array[1] ='one' ;
    $array[] ='two' ;
    $array[] ='three' ;
    print_r($array);

    ?>
```

Comment: ha ha ha ha.. your suggestion array results like $array[0] = 'one', $array[1] = 'two'.

Comment: @ Vinoth Babu that is an optional part if he want to implement.answer for him is first one.

Comment: yes boss. optional part you given will not map 1 with one and 2 with two. thats what i said. anyhow fine.. :)

Comment: @VinothBabu i never meant 1 with one i meant dynamic index creation.

Comment: ha ha ha Cool.. Thanks for changing that. Also the person who posted the question will think in a way what i thought.. :P :P :P :P

Comment: @VinothBabu but if you get it like that,it means i have not explained properly so let me change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66385/discussion-between-suchit-and-vinoth-babu).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, and if you have more key you can add into `$a` array

```
$a = array('one', 'two');
$array = array();
foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
    $array[$value] = ++$index;
}
```